# Breaking a path into 100 pixel lines

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, trigonometry, adobe-illustrator, jsfl

I have a path drawn in Illustrator, and I need to break the path into section of 100 px. I can't figure out the logic. A line consist of 2 points x1,y1 and x2, y2. And this is for a straight line. My line may have angles/curve, so what do I need to do, to figure out the distance between 2 pixels.Here is a graphic illustration of my line and the sections, which I need to select/extract:

[image]

From the shape above, I need to break it into section of lines(note these are not straight lines).
[image]

Comment: I have provided an answer, but I am curious to know why you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the [Bug Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646347/Robotics-Motion-Planning-and-Navigation-Bug-Algori). It's a very simple intuitive approach to path planning. I've uploaded an example written in LabVIEW [here](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-37150), but I know there are plenty of others available.

The Bug Algorithm generates a continuous line; a lot of data points; however you can keep a running average of the general diretion it's heading in and detect sharp changes in angles as an important node in the path. This allows you to segment paths from possibly thousands of data points into just a handful.

Comment: I am not looking for a path finding logic. I think because of the grey boxes, it gives an impression that I am looking for a solution to a path finding problem. I have a curve path drawn, now I want to break it into sections of 100 px and then make use of those sections to animate.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not processing an image then, and you already have your curve data i.e. a continuous set of data points? Or is this something you want to do in Illustrator?

Comment: Yes, its not a static raster image. I have a Path/Shape drawn in Illustrator. Because its a vector, I am assuming it must have all the points and angles. I can't figure out how to read them and then break them into chunks. I think it should be possible using JSFL, but I am not sure.

Comment: Okay, well, the algorithm is pretty simple. You iterate across all the points, and track the distance magnitude from your initial location (`lastNode`). When you exceed 100px, within a certain tolerance, you can discard all other points in between. Then you overwrite your `lastNode` with the current position and continue this pattern until you reach the end of the line. In terms of doing this within Illustrator, I'd reccomend checking out their plugin SDK. https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects in your question:

1. how do I break a path at some point,
2. how do I find points spaced by a certain distance.

To answer the first, the type of primitives that define the path matters. Assuming a sequence of Bezier cubics, you will resort to the de Casteljau's algorithm: it allows you to construct the control points that correspond to a desired section of a given Bezier arc, from the original control points. Then, a section of a path will be obtained as a starting section of an initial Bezier, then (possibly) a sequence of whole Bezier arcs, and finally the ending section of a last Bezier arc.

To answer the second, assuming that you need an accurate answer, you will need to resort to numerical integration of the arc length along the path. Refer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1171564/65203.

For a simple approximation, you can flatten the curve (approximate it as a polyline) and compute the accumulated segment lengths (or even count the pixels if your curve renderer gives you access to this information).

This process is not trivial.